# WebDriver able to locate and perform action on xpath but still "NoSuchElementException" is thrown

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nosuchelementexception

Below is the simple code to click an object using xpath. I am successfully able to locate xpath and perform the desired operation but still "**NoSuchElementException**" is thrown.

```
String localobject=OR.getProperty(object); //Obtaining xpath from object repository
we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""+localobject+"")); 
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", we);
```

Here is the trace

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #\/\/\*\[text\(\)\=\'Log\ Out\'\]
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:42:22.379Z'
System info: host: 'xxxxxxxx', ip: 'xx.xx.xx.xx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.ensureCleanSession: false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:17221/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 1617a9c2-cd03-4c77-8732-c4951fd83729
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=//*[text()='Log Out']}
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor32.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:371)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:417)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at config.Keywords.click(Keywords.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at executionEngine.DriverScript.execute_Actions(DriverScript.java:123)
    at executionEngine.DriverScript.execute_TestCase(DriverScript.java:106)
    at executionEngine.DriverScript.main(DriverScript.java:57)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all :

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #\/\/\*\[text\(\)\=\'Log\ Out\'\]
// and
Element info: {Using=id, value=//*[text()='Log Out']}
```

The expression **#//*[text()\=\'Log\ Out\']** is definitely not a valid **css selector**. Currently `CSS_Selectors` doesn't supports `text()` attribute.

Again the expression **//*[text()='Log Out']** is not a valid `id` but a potential **xpath**

### Solution

When you obtain the *xpath* from object repository ensure that you invoke it as a `String` as follows :

```
we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(localobject));
```

Comment: I used your above solution but still, I end up in the same scenario. I am performing same click operation with other xpath also in similar fashion, in all other cases it is working fine. Only with this particular xpath exception is thrown. I guess the issue is something else.Still thanks for the try.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @DebanjanB's answer:

You might try this as the element locator as well-

```
//*[contains(.,'Log Out')]
```

Try this and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi SK, I have already tried this before. Still I tried again and I get the same exception.

Comment: If you can show us the HTML Code for the page(atleast part of the Page for Logout) and I could help you better.

Comment: <TD onclick=fnLogOut() class=MenuParentNode style="CURSOR: hand; TEXT-ALIGN: right">Log Out</TD>

This is the utmost I can share. I am not allowed to share more.